# Backup server with NAS and Bacula

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, bacula

I would like to buy a NAS storage, to be used as backup server. Is it a good idea? I'm very new in this kind of things so if some one can help me. I have a dedicated server running with Debian, one friend told me that Bacula is good choise for backup the system so I was wondering what NAS I have to buy to support Bacula, I googled a bit and found that Synology may can do the trick but I don't know for which model to go or they all will work with Bacula. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Sorry but this question is too broad and requests a product recommendation, both of which are off-topic here.  Whether to use a NAS device for backup depends on your needs.

Comment: Keep in mind that Bacula, while pretty good software, is rather full-blown backup solution for managing large-scale backup solution and is rather targeted at tapes. It is not exactly easy to setup right at first shot. If you need simple backup solution for one server, get something simpler. I do have no experience with suggested rsnapshot, but can recommend [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), which works well for me. (And no, this is not meant as flame-starter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which NAS came with support for bacula, but you can simply run both the server and agent parts on your debian server, configuring your NAS as the backup destination (for example, exporting a share via SMB or NFS).

However, while bacula is an excellent tool, I suggest you to use [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org). Using it, what your NAS must support is basically SSH and rsync only. Moreover, exporting your snapshot tree via SMB or NFS, you can have an always-available and easy to use backup library.